# How to set border radius to bottom app bar in a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to set the *borderRadius* to an **Bottom Navigation App Bar** as its shown in the image. I have tried to put Bottom Navigation App Bar to a **ClipRRect** *borderRadius* and in a **Container** decoration but it didn't worked. So how can I apply the topLeft, and topRight border radius to my bottom navigation bar. Kindly help to let me know how can I do it?

[image]

main.dart

```
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Food Ordering',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue, primaryColor: Colors.white),
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/detail-page': (BuildContext context) => MyDetailPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    HomePage(),
    HomePage(),
    HomePage(),
    HomePage(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Image.asset('assets/icon-home.png'),
              title: Text('Home'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Image.asset('assets/icon-mentors.png'),
              title: Text('Mentors'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Image.asset('assets/icon-messages.png'),
              title: Text('Messages'),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Image.asset('assets/icon-settings.png'),
              title: Text('Settings'),
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
          onTap: _onItemTapped),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like not a trivial task. But probably you may need to wrap the `BottomNavigationBa`r into `Material` widget.
At least `Material`'s API docs says that it is dealing with clipping and shaping. Though I am not sure they have ready shape that you need.

Comment: Its already wraped in an MaterialApp, have a look at the updated code.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**EDIT**

Scaffold now has a property called `extendBody` which can be used to extend the body below a bottomBar. From the documentation,

> If true, and bottomNavigationBar or persistentFooterButtons is specified, then the body extends to the bottom of the Scaffold, instead of only extending to the top of the bottomNavigationBar or the persistentFooterButtons.

This means that all you need to do is

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Some Text'),
      ),
      body: bodyContent,
      extendBody: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
    );
  }

  Widget get bodyContent {
    return Container(color: Colors.red);
  }

  Widget get bottomNavigationBar {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(40),
        topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: '1'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.usb), label: '2'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.assignment_ind), label: '3'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.multiline_chart), label: '4'),
        ],
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**OUTDATED**

Put it inside a stack. Don't add the Bottom Navigation Bar to the scaffold directly.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Some Text'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          bodyContent,
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: bottomNavigationBar,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget get bodyContent {
    return Container(color: Colors.red);
  }

  Widget get bottomNavigationBar {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(40),
        topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('1')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.usb), title: Text('2')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.assignment_ind), title: Text('3')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.multiline_chart), title: Text('4')),
        ],
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, if your goal is to only put a borderRadius you can just use ClipRRect and apply your desired borderRadius to it.
Here is my implementation of the solution:

```
  ClipRRect _getBtmNavBar() {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
        topRight: Radius.circular(25),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onTabTapped,
        selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black87,
          fontSize: 16,
        ),
        iconSize: 35,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black54,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: kBottomNavBarBgColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
// more BottomNavigationBarItem() goes here.
```

Then plug it directly into your bottomNavigationBar

Code Example:

```
return Scaffold(
// more Scaffold code goes here

//bottom navigationBar
      bottomNavigationBar: _getBtmNavBar(),
);
```

Answer (score 7):

**You may user bellow like .**

1. My bottomNavigationBar image is look like
   [image]

2. here is thecode

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class BottomTab extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _BottomTab();
      }
    }

    class _BottomTab extends State<BottomTab> {
      int _selectedTabIndex = 0;

      List _pages = [
        Text("Home"),
        Text("Order"),
        Text("Notfication"),
        Text("More"),
      ];

      _changeIndex(int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedTabIndex = index;
          print("index..." + index.toString());
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('bottom nav bar'),
          ),
          body: Center(child: _pages[_selectedTabIndex]),
          bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
        );
      }

      Widget get bottomNavigationBar {
        return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30), topLeft: Radius.circular(30)),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(color: Colors.black38, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 10),
              ],
            ),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
              ),
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                currentIndex: _selectedTabIndex,
                onTap: _changeIndex,
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                selectedFontSize: 12,
                unselectedFontSize: 12,
                selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
                unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[500],
                showUnselectedLabels: true,
                items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
                    title: new Text('Home'),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
                    title: new Text('Order'),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.mail),
                    title: new Text('Messages'),
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz_rounded), title: Text('More')),
                ],
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just include the BottomNavigationBar inside the body, inside a circular border container. [Like this (See the picture attached!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3mXL.jpg)

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: new AssetImage("assets/images/background.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(child: _children[_currentIndex]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(0)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        offset: Offset(0.0, 1.00), //(x,y)
                        blurRadius: 4.00,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        spreadRadius: 1.00),
                  ],
                ),
                height: 70,
                child: ClipRRect(
                    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(25),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(0)),
                    child: Container(
                      child: BottomNavigationBar(
                        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 50),
                        showSelectedLabels: false,
                        showUnselectedLabels: false,
                        onTap: onTabTapped,
                        // new
                        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
                        // new
                        items: [
                          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.phone,
                              size: 30,
                            ),
                            title: Text('Calls'),
                          ),
                          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.mail,
                              size: 30,
                            ),
                            title: Text('Messages'),
                          ),
                          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.person,
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                              title: Text('Profile'))
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
              )
            ],
          )),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: You don't actually have to include the bottom navigation bar in separately, but include in the body also inside a circular container. I have achieved this, check the photos attached