# How to show a Container fixed at bottom of screen without using bottom navigation bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter project, I have a container with some icons and text below them. I want this entire container to be fixed at bottom of the screen without using bottom navigation bar like the below image-

[image]

So, I need an entire example to fix that container at bottom and keep my other components inside body with a scroll view.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet??

Comment: Actually I did this using Bottom navigation bar, but I have no idea how to do it only using container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set border radius to bottom app bar in a flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577265/how-to-set-border-radius-to-bottom-app-bar-in-a-flutter-app)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok,
Here you go....

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Header"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text("Hello"),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: double.maxFinite,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(

            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0))
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward), onPressed: (){},),
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward), onPressed: (){},),
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left), onPressed: (){},),
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward), onPressed: (){},),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. But I am having another problem if I want the body scrolling with keeping that bottom container fixed there. What should I do?

Comment: Just replace the `Container` inside `Expanded` with `ListView`

Comment: One more suggestion required- If I want to wrap the Row of IconButtons(Bottom bar) in a card with same top border radius elevation. What should I do?

Comment: Can you share some ui code so I can understand more?

Comment: Please check the question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120155/how-to-make-a-bottom-bar-with-border-radius-using-card-and-add-elevation-to-it-i

Answer (score 8):

If you want to make a **scrollable item/listview** in the body section and want a fixed bottom container you can follow this code given below :

**important note : Make sure wrap the listview with Expanded**

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class ShoppingCart extends StatelessWidget {    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    //your code
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.delete_outline_sharp,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  )),

              //Add more icon here
            ],
            elevation: 0,
            centerTitle: false,
            title:
                Text("Shopping Cart", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: shoppingCartItems.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 15.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          // color: Color(0xffF3F3F3),
                          color: Colors.red,
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                      height: 120,
                      width: 360,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 150,
              width: double.maxFinite,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange[200],
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0))),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

[image]

**Update :**

This is built in now. You can use **bottomNavigationBar** and customize is as below :

```
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: //set your height here
          width: double.maxFinite, //set your width here
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.orange,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0))
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[

              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward), onPressed: (){
//on Presses functionaluty goes here
},),
              //add as many tabs as you want here
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    child: Container(
      height: 50.0,
      width: double.maxFinite,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0))
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward), onPressed: (){},),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward), onPressed: (){},),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left), onPressed: (){},),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward), onPressed: (){},),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, add comments

Comment: The question is without using bottomNavigationbar

Answer (score 0):

That's the best option, mate. It already defines what you need.

From the updated documentation:

"A material widget that's displayed at the bottom of an app for selecting among a small number of views, typically between three and five.

The bottom navigation bar consists of multiple items in the form of text labels, icons, or both, laid out on top of a piece of material. It provides quick navigation between the top-level views of an app."

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html