# How to make a bottom bar with border radius using Card and add elevation to it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter project, I have created a **bottom bar** using **Container**.

Here's the code given for that-

```
   Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 300,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              getCarousel(),
              Column(

                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 240,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),

                  Container(
                    color: Colors.teal,
                   height: 300,
                  ),


                ],
              ),
              Container(
                height: 350,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 72.0),
                  itemCount: itemList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                    return new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[

                        Expanded(
                          child: new Container(
                            width: 160,
                            height: 320,
                            color: Colors.yellow[100],
                          ),
                        ),

                        new Divider()
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        Container(
          height: 60,
          width: double.maxFinite,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
              borderRadius:
              BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0))),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              showBottomIcons(Icons.home, "Home", "/HomeScreen"),
              showBottomIcons(
                  Icons.category, "Category", "/CategoryScreen"),
              showBottomIcons(Icons.shopping_cart, "Cart", "/CartScreen"),
              showBottomIcons(Icons.person, "Account", "/AccountScreen"),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  )
```

The Output of the screen looks like that-

[image]

Now, I want to switch the **Container to Card**. **But I got some problems-**

1. Card is taking some by default padding and the border radius at two top corners are not working.
2. As the top two corners are rounded, the background is getting white(As you can see in image). I want that space red colored.
3. I need some elevation with border radius like below image using card-

   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. & 3. You don't actually need card widget for this. You can add shadow on your container itself.
2. You have to use stack to achieve this.

As I am hoping you are using the same code as my previous answer of your another question. I have updated the answer with stack layout & your requirements

```
       Container(
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned.fill(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Hello"),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      boxShadow: [
                        new BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          blurRadius: 2.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0))),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
```

**editing steps for your code**

I will try to explain the changes.

1. You have multiple items in your `Column`. Move everything except `Container` which you used as bottom bar (the last child of column) to another `Column` widget.
2. Put this last container child inside `Align` widget like my code
3. Put the newly created `Column` in `Positioned.fill` widget.
4. Change `column` of `scaffold` to `Stack`
5. Set this stack's fit property as `StackFit.expand`

   6. The body of you Scaffold should look like this.

```
Stack(
  fit: StackFit.expand,
  children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
           ....   // Your page body childs
           ]
        ),
    ),
    Align(
       alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
       child: ...    // Your bottom bar container
    )
  ]
)
```

> To know more about stack visit [here](https://youtu.be/liEGSeD3Zt8)

Comment: It's quite tough for me to understand your code properly as I am a beginner. Some explanation about using the Stack would help. **I have also edited the question** , now you can see the entire **Scaffold**. So, it would be very kind of you if you suggest me what changes should I make in the current code.

Comment: @Asif I have made changes to my answer please check.

Comment: thanks it works, but the only problem that I am facing now is- the bottom bar(Container)  background has become transparent now. I want this to have fixed white background.

Comment: You must have removed the color property from bottom container's boxdecoration. Check that.

Comment: No I haven't removed the BoxDecoration Color, I set up the widget according to your suggestion. Please check my Align code for Bottom bar-

https://codeshare.io/5ZRD6n

Comment: Hmm everything looks good. Can you share me the screenshot of issue??

Comment: I have edited the question, check the first image in the question.

Comment: Ok that's not helpful at all as the colours are all messed up. If you can also the stack withbasics widgets that might be helpful to understand from which colour is related to which Widget.

Comment: Well that's the problem actually, in the image you can see as my bottom navigation background is transparent the scrolling screen of two different background yellow and red is showing behind the bottom bar. Yes, the click action is working well

Comment: Also can you confirm if you can click on those bottom icons or not?

Comment: Yes, I can click on those bottom icons

Comment: It's very difficult to tell the exact cause without the actual code. I will try to investigate but it may take time.

Comment: Thanks, I am also sharing you the entire body part of my code. It may help you-  https://codeshare.io/5ZRD6n

Comment: Everything seems ok. We can just hit and try few things to resolve this. First try another color instead of white. If it's still transparent this means something wrong with Widget tree. Entirely stop the app from ide and restart. Let me know the result.

Comment: If this not work try setting the gradient colour of boxdecoration `gradient: new LinearGradient(
        colors: [Colors.red, Colors.cyan],
        begin: Alignment.centerRight,
        end: Alignment.centerLeft
      ),`

Comment: Thanks @Aakash. It was mainly my emulator problem and showing shader compilation error. I reinstalled another emulator & the problem is fixed. Thanks a lot for all the efforts.

Comment: No problem buddy :)