# Flutter how to add margin or padding in BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to make bottom navigation bar, but with padding left and right on the screen. Right now I wrap the BottomNavigationBar with container and add padding there. The problem is the BottomNavigationBar default background still wrap all the layer, so could we remove the background color there?

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tns5f.png)

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO2lq.png)

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      elevation: 0,
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.local_activity), title: Text('Activity')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.inbox), title: Text('Inbox')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Profile')),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Edit: I have removed background color in scaffold and all theme, but when you have scrolled item, you could see there is still background there
[Remove Scafold bg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KruE9.png)

Edit 2: here the code for the activity

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 850,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    )
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _children[0],
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(200), topRight: Radius.circular(200)),
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            showUnselectedLabels: true,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            elevation: 0,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.local_activity), title: Text('Activity')),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.inbox), title: Text('Inbox')),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Profile')),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX7Yb.png)

Comment: it should work as you're expecting. I think you have set background color on your scafold or any other wrapper method that you have used ..do check or share full page source code

Comment: I have tested too, there is no issue. you might have set color to the navigation bar via themedata or set background color on your parent element

Comment: if we have scroll item in list view, we could see the background still there

Comment: You're definitely doing something wrong. Post your complete code of the activity in which this issue is happening if you want help.

Comment: helo @OMiShah I have post the code of the activity and the screenshot of the result, could you take a look

Comment: still doesn't works @Eugene, have you tried to compile the code?

Comment: @Msfrn you need to use ``positioned`` with ``stack`` to achieve so. Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56585903/5882307

Comment: Wow, it's works, thanks @OMiShah

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to put the `Body` and the `BottomNavigationBar` under a `Stack` so that the `BottomNavigationBar` can be placed on top of the main body content.

**Your complete code will be:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> _children = [
      Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 850, // use 'MediaQuery.of(context).size.height' to fit the screen height,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      )
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              _children[0],
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: bottomNavigationBar(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

Widget bottomNavigationBar() {
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.amber,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(200), topRight: Radius.circular(200)),
    ),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      elevation: 0,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.local_activity), title: Text('Activity')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.inbox), title: Text('Inbox')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Profile')),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

**Partial code from:**

[How to set border radius to bottom app bar in a flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577265/how-to-set-border-radius-to-bottom-app-bar-in-a-flutter-app/56585903#56585903)

Answer (score 14):

I know it's kinda late. But this should help future viewers like me.

The `icon` parameter from `BottomNavigationBarItem` takes in a `Widget`. What I did is to just wrap my `Icon` into a `Container` and defined a `padding`.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
 icon: Container(
   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
   child: Icon(
     Icons.home
   )
 )    
)
```

Comment: That's the same solution i adopted, but this only moves the icon, and not the label!

Comment: How can we move label also ?

Comment: My answer provides the solution to this @m.i.n.a.r. and Zain https://stackoverflow.com/a/74689920/7323067

Answer (score 1):

For some one is looking for solution:
You can wrap BottomNatigationBar in a Container with padding/margin properties, set same background color an set elevation of BottomNavigationBar to 0.
eg:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
  child: BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: (index) {
      controller.tabIndex.value = index;
    },
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0,
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you came here searching for how to add a padding at the bottom of the `BottomNavigationBar`, here it is the solution:

Wrap the `BottomNavigationBar` with a `MediaQuery` and provide a `bottom` padding, this value is taken in consideration when build the bottom bar.

```dart
MediaQuery(
  data: MediaQueryData(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10) // here is the padding
  ),
  child: BottomNavigationBar(),
),
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work anymore on Flutter 3.7.7

Comment: I think this should use viewPadding instead of padding