# How do I put the bottom navigation bar in flutter lower on iOS?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently developing a Flutter app and I've noticed that there's a problem with the positioning of my bottom navigation bar on iOS devices. Specifically, there's a rounded bevel on the bottom of the screen that causes the bottom nav bar to be positioned too high, which looks like it's floating above the bottom of the screen.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgYqs.png)

This is my code for the `BottomNavigationBar`:

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            selectedFontSize: 0,
            unselectedFontSize: 0,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            showSelectedLabels: false,
            showUnselectedLabels: false,
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              // ...
            ],
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF1B1D26),
            selectedItemColor: const Color(0xff00B2FF),
            unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xff0171A1),
            elevation: 0.0,
            currentIndex: _selectedPage,
            onTap: (index) => setState(() => _selectedPage = index),
          ),
        ),
```

I've tried adding padding to the bottom of the screen, but that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried using the SafeArea widget, but that doesn't do anything at all.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem? I'd appreciate any help or guidance you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879493/flutter-how-to-add-margin-or-padding-in-bottomnavigationbar - maybe this issue will help.