# FLUTTER bottom navigation bar in dark mode

Tags: flutter

how to add border color to bottom navigation bar at dark mode

code:

bottomNavigationBarTheme:

```
     BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
     
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
      elevation: 20.0,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      
    ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577265/how-to-set-border-radius-to-bottom-app-bar-in-a-flutter-app did it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add the `bottomNavigationBar` in the scaffold not using the built-in bottomNavigationBar argument, but doing it from the body. Then something like this could work if you only need a top bar, for instance:

```dart
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Container(width: double.maxFinite, height: 4, child: Material(elevation: 20.0, color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent),),
          BottomNavigationBar(
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.music_note), label: 'Audio'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt), label: 'Camera'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

This code simply places an orange triangle on top of the bottomNavigationBar.

However, if you want more control over the border you could wrap the BottomNavigationBar in a widget, as suggested in the post commented by @Muhtar, [link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577265/how-to-set-border-radius-to-bottom-app-bar-in-a-flutter-app).

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem

code:

bottomNavigationBar: Container(

```
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             border: Border(
               top: BorderSide(
                 color: Colors.grey,
                 style: BorderStyle.solid,
                 width: 1.3

               ),
             ),
          
        ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: cubit.current,
            items: cubit.bottom_nav_items,
            onTap: (value) {
              cubit.changeBottomNavItem(value);
            },
          ),
        ),
```